# SpringBoot jUnit is not loading application-dev.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, junit

I am using SpringBoot for latest development.Profile based configuration we have so there are 3 files are there

> application-{env}.properties, env means dev,stage and prod

When I run the project locally in eclipse using `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` run configuration it is picking configurations from application-dev.properties. But If I try to run a jUnit, it is expecting application.properties otherwise throwing error.I put a application.properties it is working fine.Please tell me how to configure JUnit with profile based so that which will pick application-dev.properties.Please give your input on this, thanks in advance.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ProcessingServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void testlet2MeIn() throws Exception{
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `setProperty` ?

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ProcessingServiceTest {
    public ProcessingServiceTest(){
       System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active","dev");
    }
    @Test
    public void testlet2MeIn() throws Exception{
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can specify the properties files using `@TestPropertySource`and specify which file should be used to load properties for tests

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-dev.properties")
```

Or
the simplest way is to use this on your test class `@ActiveProfiles("dev")`

Comment: Instead of setting the profiles explicitly as suggested in some other answer you can use this annotation on your test class.
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
or 
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-dev.properties")